# How can I use very small numbers in Python with scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, physics

I am trying to simulate a physics situation that involves calculating very small numbers. When the numbers get too small the values become garbage and/or are rounded to zero which doesn't help me. I am also using the scipy constants module for certain constants. I am trying to calculate the position using Euler's Method and calculating the velocity using momentum. The physics isn't the important part in this problem.

I have tried using the decimal module but think I am running into problems when using decimal and scipy constants together. Also, when using Decimal, do i need to convert every variable into Decimal before calculating?

In the loop below, it can only compute about 3 values before the error occurs.

```py
    # Create the arrays for velocity and position
    vx = sp.zeros(n+1)
    vy = sp.zeros(n+1)
    x = sp.zeros(n+1)
    y = sp.zeros(n+1)
    time = sp.zeros(n+1)

    # Initialize our values
    vx[0] = vx0
    vy[0] = vy0
    x[0] = x0
    y[0] = y0
    time[0] = 0
    i = 0

    while y[i] > 0:
        step = math.sqrt(x[i]**2 + y[i]**2) / cs.c
        vx[i + 1] = vx[i] + (((cs.hbar * cs.c) /  (2*cs.electron_mass)) * (x[i] / (x[i]**2 + y[i]**2)))
        vy[i + 1] = vy[i] + (((cs.hbar * cs.c) /  (2*cs.electron_mass)) * (y[i] / (x[i]**2 + y[i]**2)))
        x[i + 1] = x[i] + (vx[i] * step)
        y[i + 1] = y[i] + (vy[i] * step)
        i += 1
```

```py
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Comment: See [the SciPy documentation on extended float precision](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision); this is a hard limitation of python, in this case. As a workaround, would it be possible to uniformly increase everything by a few magnitudes, do the calculation, and then decrease the result by the same number of magnitudes?

Comment: "I have tried using the decimal module but think I am running into problems when using decimal and scipy constants together. Also, when using Decimal, do i need to convert every variable into Decimal before calculating?" please elaborate on exactly what you tried. `decimal.Decimal` can handle arbitrarily small numbers (as long as you have the memory). Yes, to work with them, you have to convert everything to `Decimal` objects rather than `float` objects

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I looked at the datatypes and switched my arrays to an numpy.longdouble. This really didn't fix anything, but I scaled everything and then did that calculations. This seemed to work for now. Thank you!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried changing everything to Decimal but I found out numpy arrays cannot be converted to the Decimal datatype.

Comment: @ahayes24 well, you can use the `object` dtype, but then you might as well just use a `list`

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I'd start with using natural units , with hbar=c=m=1. Then re-evaluate if underflow persists or not.